# Gradle : use a task to disable another task

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I have three gradle tasks (this is kotlin code inside a plugin):

```
project.task<Task>("checkNeeded") {
    doLast {
        if (someTest()) {
            listOf("SomeCopy", "SomeAction")
                    .map { project.tasks[it] as AbstractTask }
                    .forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
        }
    }
}

project.task<Copy>("SomeCopy") {
    dependsOn("checkNeeded")
    from(wherever)
    into(whatever)
}

project.task<Task>("SomeAction") {
    dependsOn("checkNeeded")
    doLast {
        /* something magical */
    }
}
```

So, both tasks `SomeCopy` and `someAction` depend on `checkNeeded`. The role of `checkNeeded` is to disable these two task if it finds that they are not needed.

However, this crashes with the following exception: `Cannot call Task.setEnabled(boolean) on task ':SomeCopy' after task has started execution`.

So, how can I have a task guaranteed to run before other tasks that can disable other tasks if they are not needed?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this issue with `onlyIf`:

```
var needed by Delegates.notNull<Boolean>()

project.task<Task>("checkNeeded") {
    doLast {
        needed = !someTest()
    }
}

project.task<Copy>("SomeCopy") {
    dependsOn("checkNeeded")
    onlyIf { needed }
    from(wherever)
    into(whatever)
}

project.task<Task>("SomeAction") {
    dependsOn("checkNeeded")
    onlyIf { needed }
    doLast {
        /* something magical */
    }
}
```

Note that the `checkNeeded` task is not really necessary, but I like to have it to know, in the process, when the check is made. I could have done:

```
val needed by lazy { !someTest() }

project.task<Copy>("SomeCopy") {
    onlyIf { needed }
    from(wherever)
    into(whatever)
}

project.task<Task>("SomeAction") {
    onlyIf { needed }
    doLast {
        /* something magical */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dependsOn` does set the order. It may make sense to move the `if` outside the `checkNeeded` task and place it either in the build script (it will be executed in the configuration phase) or in the `afterEvaluate {...}` block (it will still be executed in the configuration phase, but later)

Another option is to execute `checkNeeded` task explicitly before running one of the `SomeCopy` or `SomeAction`